# Convert a date to correct date and time based on timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js

My app gets an array of events from an external source. Each event has a start date like `20220925000000 +0000`. The format is `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` and the last part is timezone which is not always `+0000`.

I need to store the events and show the right start date and time to each user (Around the globe) based on their timezone. I've searched and read some SO questions but it is still confusing to me. What is the correct approach?

Comment: Is the format always `yyyymmddhhmmss`?

Answer (score -1):

```
// first parse the date using a regex:

const [m, year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, timezone] = '20220925000000 +0000'.match(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}) (\+\d{4})/);


// Then log it with proper input format for date object:
const str = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}${timezone}`;

// pass it to Date constructor and call `toLocaleString()` to get user's local format. 
console.log(new Date(str).toLocaleString());
```

Comment: That's not parsing any dates...

Comment: pass your string in. You didn't give me an example.

Comment: `console.log(new Date('2022-09-25').toLocaleString());
9/24/2022, 5:00:00 PM`

Comment: There is an example string in the question. I'm also not the OP.

Comment: i updated the answer. Keep in mind only do this in the browser. If you're storing dates in a db, you'll want to do `toISOString()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm the OP.